# "Failed to start lvm2.service: Unit lvm2.service is masked"

Tags: lvm

I am following https://wiki.debian.org/LVM on Lubuntu 18.04

I was wondering why I get the following problems. Thanks.

```
$ sudo apt-get install system-config-lvm
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package system-config-lvm

$ sudo service lvm2 start
Failed to start lvm2.service: Unit lvm2.service is masked.
```

I still can't get it right.

```
$ sudo systemctl mask lvm2 
Created symlink /etc/systemd/system/lvm2.service → /dev/null.

$ sudo systemctl enable lvm2 
Synchronizing state of lvm2.service with SysV service script with /lib/systemd/systemd-sysv-install.
Executing: /lib/systemd/systemd-sysv-install enable lvm2
Failed to enable unit: Unit file /etc/systemd/system/lvm2.service is masked.

$ sudo systemctl unmask lvm2 
Removed /etc/systemd/system/lvm2.service.

$ sudo systemctl enable lvm2 
Synchronizing state of lvm2.service with SysV service script with /lib/systemd/systemd-sysv-install.
Executing: /lib/systemd/systemd-sysv-install enable lvm2
Failed to enable unit: Unit file /lib/systemd/system/lvm2.service is masked.

$ sudo service lvm2 start
Failed to start lvm2.service: Unit lvm2.service is masked.
```

Comment: @JdeBP what is the solution? The linked reply doesn't give a solution.

Comment: I think your native systemd services are already working. So just remask lvm2.service and don't do anything.

Comment: @炸 do u mean "unmask" by "remask"? How do you verify that it is already working?