# Why can't I create a physical volume?

Tags: ubuntu, lvm

I was wondering why I can't create a physical volume? Every settings are default for lvm just installed (
For `cat /etc/lvm/lvm.conf`  see https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/QqrszWR8M9/).

Is it because of ["Failed to start lvm2.service: Unit lvm2.service is masked"](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/502363/failed-to-start-lvm2-service-unit-lvm2-service-is-masked)?  Thanks.

```
$ sudo parted -l
Model: ATA TOSHIBA MQ01ABF0 (scsi)
Disk /dev/sda: 500GB
Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/512B
Partition Table: gpt
Disk Flags: 

Number  Start   End    Size   File system  Name                  Flags
 1      1049kB  538MB  537MB  fat32        EFI System Partition  boot, esp
 2      538MB   500GB  500GB  ext4
$ sudo lvmdiskscan
  /dev/sda1 [     512.00 MiB] 
  /dev/sda2 [    <465.26 GiB] 
  0 disks
  2 partitions
  0 LVM physical volume whole disks
  0 LVM physical volumes

$ sudo pvcreate /dev/sda
  Device /dev/sda excluded by a filter.

$ sudo lvmdiskscan
  /dev/sda1 [     512.00 MiB] 
  /dev/sda2 [    <465.26 GiB] 
  0 disks
  2 partitions
  0 LVM physical volume whole disks
  0 LVM physical volumes


$ sudo pvcreate /dev/sda2
  Can't open /dev/sda2 exclusively.  Mounted filesystem?
```

Comment: I do not. Why default configurations do that?

Comment: It is in lvm.conf

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're trying to use the entire `/dev/sda` for a PV. But you've got (at least) two partitions on that disk (`sda1` and `sda2`), so LVM is rightly refusing to honour your request.

Comment: Thanks. `sudo pvcreate /dev/sda2` doesn't work either

Comment: It's got a filesystem on it. LVM is doing its best to stop you breaking your system.

Comment: Must a physical volume be created from a partition without filesystem?

Comment: Yes. Absolutely.

Comment: Where is that mentioned in documentation?

Comment: First couple of paragraphs for `man pvcreate`.

Comment: Thanks. `/dev/sda2` is a single partition, containing `/` and `/home`, and I want to separate them into different logical volumes. What shall I do, if I can't mark `/dev/sda2` as a physical volume?

Comment: Borrow or otherwise obtain an extra disk. Backup your data, and reinstall.

Comment: Thanks. WIth what others have told me, I am still confused https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/502437/how-shall-i-create-a-physical-volume-from-a-partition-containing