# We can make a disk a PV by `pvcreate`, if and only if the disk has only one partition?

Tags: partition, lvm

Manpage of pvcreate says

> pvcreate initializes a PV so that it is recognized as belonging to LVM, and allows the PV to be
>   used in a VG. A PV can be a disk partition, **whole disk**, meta device, or loopback file.

Why doesn't the following `pvcreate` command fail to mark a disk as PV then?

```
$ sudo parted -l
Model: ATA TOSHIBA MQ01ABF0 (scsi)
Disk /dev/sda: 500GB
Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/512B
Partition Table: gpt
Disk Flags: 

Number  Start   End    Size   File system  Name                  Flags
 1      1049kB  538MB  537MB  fat32        EFI System Partition  boot, esp
 2      538MB   500GB  500GB  ext4
$ sudo lvmdiskscan
  /dev/sda1 [     512.00 MiB] 
  /dev/sda2 [    <465.26 GiB] 
  0 disks
  2 partitions
  0 LVM physical volume whole disks
  0 LVM physical volumes

$ sudo pvcreate /dev/sda
  Device /dev/sda excluded by a filter.
```

roaima wrote in https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/502428/674:

> You're trying to use the entire /dev/sda for a PV. But you've got (at least) two partitions on that disk (sda1 and sda2), so LVM is rightly refusing to honour your request.

Does it mean that we can make a disk a PV by `pvcreate`, if and only if the disk has only one partition? In other words, we can't make a disk a PV by `pvcreate`, if and only if the disk has more than one partitions?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You said yourself:

> A PV can be a disk partition, whole disk, meta device, or loopback file

I don't understand your question. A PV can be a partition or a whole disk. Delete all partitions and you will be able to use the whole disk. If you don't want to use the whole disk, then use a partition instead.

You should also know that one partition that covers the whole disk space could make less trouble.

Please read this answer before you wipe your hdd: [What is the best practice for adding disks in LVM](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/76642/332764).

Comment: My question is "Does it mean that we can make a disk a PV by pvcreate, if and only if the disk has only one partition? In other words, we can't make a disk a PV by pvcreate, if and only if the disk has more than one partitions?"

Comment: You can't make the whole disk a PV if there is at least one partition on it (because pvcreate won't let you).

Comment: What do you mean a disk without a partition? Any disk without being partitioned is a partition by itself

Comment: “Any disk without being partitioned” is a disk with no partitions. It isn’t a partition by itself. When you get a new disk, or if you overwrite a disk with zeros, it’s empty, with no partition table, let alone partitions.

Comment: @Tim If you delete `/dev/sda1` and `/dev/sda2` with gparted or any other partitioning program, then your disk is without partitions.

Answer (score 1):

No.

I have absolutely no experience with this, but from the information in the question. No.

You can pvcreate a partition or a disk, or …

It is stopping you, because it sees that the device you have asked to process, has partitions on it. The important word here is **partition**s (ignore pluralisation).

So the logical predicate you are after is:

```
Partitions on device implies, pvcreate refuses to work (destroy data).
```

If you want to do the whole disk, then remove partitions. However it looks like you have a boot partition, so you may want to `pvcreate` `/dev/sda2`.