# Is a disk without being partitioned a partition by itself?

Tags: partition, lvm

From [We can make a disk a PV by `pvcreate`, if and only if the disk has only one partition?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/502709/we-can-make-a-disk-a-pv-by-pvcreate-if-and-only-if-the-disk-has-only-one-part#comment926945_502714)

> You can't make the whole disk a PV **if there is at least one partition on it** (because pvcreate won't let you).

When considering disks and partitions as concepts in operating systems, is it correct that a disk without being partitioned is a partition by itself?

If no, what is the difference between a disk without being partitioned and a disk with only one partition?

Can `pvcreate` mark a disk with only one partition as a PV?

Comment: Partitions exist when defined by a partition table. For this reason I wouldn't consider a disk to be a partition

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A disk without being partitioned is a disk with no partitions or partition table; it’s not a partition (a partition separates something into parts, even if it’s only one; a whole disk isn’t separated into parts).

A disk with one partition is a disk with a partition table of some sort (there are several partitioning schemes), with one entry in the table defining a partition.

`pvcreate` can create a physical volume using an entire disk or a partition. By default it will refuse to create a physical volume using an entire disk if it already contains a partition table.

(Note that `pvcreate` doesn’t “mark” an existing feature — disk or partition —, it creates a physical volume, which involves writing metadata.)

Comment: Thanks. "By default it will refuse to create a physical volume using an entire disk if it already contains a partition table." What is non default case?

Comment: `-f` or `-ff` IIRC.

Answer (score 2):

They are both **block storage devices**. In principle one could add a partition table to a partition, thus adding partitions to it. However Operating Systems may not recursively traverse partitions, so they may no be found, and thus may not be treated the same.

Note: Extended partitions are a partition with a partition table within.

Comment: partition table is more like a simple kernel built-in device-mapper solution. Pretty old, but still in  common use.

Comment: @炸鱼薯条德里克  "partition table is more like a simple kernel built-in device-mapper solution."  Is a partition table a mapping from what to what?  Is LVM's device-mapper solution a mapping from what to what?

Comment: from one physical disk to several partition block devices. from physical disks to LVs.@Tim

Answer (score 1):

> You can't make the whole disk a PV if there is at least one partition
>   on it (because pvcreate won't let you).

All this is saying is that `pvcreate` refuses to wipe out your partition table if one exists. The point of this is to prevent data loss if a user accidentally runs `pvcreate /dev/sda`.

If `/dev/sda` isn't partitioned you can run `pvcreate /dev/sda` to make the **whole disk** (even the area of the disk where a partition table would exist) a PV.

If `/dev/sda` is partitioned (e.g. MBR or GPT) `pvcreate` doesn't want to take a chance ("it won't let you"). This is a safety mechanism, not a technical limitation.